Question about Fourier-coefficients in Griffith's Problem 3.15 (Electrodynamics)
I am having some trouble with problem 3.15 from Griffith's Electrodynamics. It states the following:

A rectangular pipe, running parallel to the $z$-axis (from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$), has three grounded metal sides, at $y = 0, y = a$ , and $x = 0$. The fourth side, at $x = b$, is maintained at a specified potential $V_0(y)$.

The first part asks to find a general formula for the potential inside the pipe. By using separation of variables and imposing the boundary conditions I obtained that
$$
V_n(x,y) = c_n \sin\left(\frac{\pi n y}{a}\right) \sinh\left(\frac{\pi n x}{a}\right)
$$
for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. By the superposition principle, we can make linear combinations, so
we can write the general solution as:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \sin\left(\frac{\pi n y}{a}\right) \sinh\left(\frac{\pi n x}{a}\right)
$$
Now I need to find a formula for $c_n$. Since $V(b,y) = V_0(y)$ we have that
$$
V_0(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \sin\left(\frac{\pi n y}{a}\right) \underbrace{\sinh\left(\frac{\pi n b}{a}\right)}_{=\text{constant}}
$$
From this I tried to determine $c_n$ by multiplying both sides by $\sin(\pi m y/a)$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and then integrating from $0$ to $2a$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2a}V_0(y) \sin\left(\frac{\pi m y}{a} \right)dy &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \sinh\left(\frac{\pi n b}{a} \right)\underbrace{ \int_{0}^{2a} \sin \left(\frac{\pi n y}{a} \right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi m y }{a} \right)dy }_{a \cdot \delta_{m,n} }\\ 
&=c_n a \sinh \left(\frac{\pi n b}{a}\right)
\end{align*}
which gives us a formula for $c_n$:
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{a\sin(\pi n b/a} \int_{0}^{2a}V_0(y) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n y}{a} \right)dy
$$
Thinking I did it correctly, I moved to part (ii) of the question where we fix $V_0(y) = V_0$ (constant). However, if I plug in $V_0(y) = V_0$ then I get that all $c_n$ are zero (which is not the correct answer). I don't know where I went wrong here. Could anyone help me?
Edit: I suspect it has something to do with the integration limits. The book uses an integral from $0$ to $a$ instead of $0$ to $2a$. I still don't know what went wrong in the derivation I did.

Why integrate to $y=2a$?

@d_b I didn't have a specific reason to integrate to $2a$ except for the fact that the integral on the right hand side turns into a kronecker-delta so that we can isolate $c_n$. I'm just wondering why this doesn't result in the correct answer

Please consider changing the title. As it stands, it only describes where you found the problem and does not describe what the problem you actually have.

@want2know The issue is that the boundary condition only specifies $V_0(y)$ from $y=0$ to $y=a$. You need to find the Fourier coefficients using only the boundary potential from $y=0$ to $y=a$. I suggest re-reading the section of Griffiths preceding this problem.

@d_b Ahh thank you, that solves my problem. I only really considered the calculation instead of the actual problem.

@KyleKanos Thanks for the suggestion
